# Client side send value to node.js and set as cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, middleware

I'm using

```
app.use(require('./middleware/im')({
   maxAge: 30 * 1000,
   reapInterval: 20 * 1000,
   authentication: require('./libs/authentication/' + AUTH_LIBRARY)
}));
```

to authenticate the user(cookie based) in my node.js/express.js. Now my problem is I need my client side(a PHP + javascript) server send a cookie value to the node server via GET(jsonp) so I can authenticate the user. But If I do:

```
app.get('/cookie', function(){//set cookie here});
```

it won't work because the auth code in the middleware fires before they even call the action. What should I do so I can send a cookie(or any string) to the node.js server before the middleware fires? If that's not possible, is there any alternative way I can use so I can let the node.js server get the user's userid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To intercept the request, before your `'.middleware/im'` can get to it, you need to create your own middlware, which is surprisingly simple (the following goes before your call to `app.use(require('./middleware/im')({ ...`):

```
app.use(cookieDetect);
function cookieDetect (request, response, next) {
    if (request.url === "/cookie") {
        // do your stuff here
    } else {
        next(); // keep the middleware chain going
    }
}
```

Btw, as a JavaScript syntactical note, when you use function declarations (different than `var myFunc = function () { ...`), "scope hoisting" happens: that particular function declaration is available at the very beginning of that scope-level's execution, instead of from where it appears in the code. Which is why I'm able to `app.use` it *before* it appears in the code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. So I should "GET" the cookie in the function app.get('/cookie') and then I store it in "do your stuff here"?

Comment: @jackhao No, you'd want to do all that stuff within the `if (request.url === "/cookie") { ...` and remove the `app.get("/cookie", function () { ... });`.

Comment: Oh, ok that makes sense now. So right now I can just use jsonp push stuff to node server using GET and set cookie here... Thanks so much!